# Intellij IDEA (Ultimate) with Glassfish 5.0 (Local) Debugger Settings

Tags: java, debugging, intellij-idea, javaagents, glassfish-5

- I have a **Java Web Application** and a web container **Glassfish 5.0** with some **custom java agent attached to the container**.
- I want to **Debug my application as well as attach a Remote Debugger to Debug my Agent code simultaneously**.
- I am using **Intellij IDEA Ultimate**.
- Now in the Intellij Run Configuration for Glassfish, I do the usual settings with some domain name. For Debug options ***"-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,address=9100,server=y,suspend=n"***
  I want to make ***'servey=y, suspend=y'*** , NO COMPROMISE ON THAT.
- I try doing that by changing the **'domain.xml'** but when I open my intellij glassfish configuration setting it gives me **'Warning : Debugger Settings are Invalid...**' , I click `Fix` and the ***domain.xml is changed back to default*** with **'server=n,suspend=y'**.
- I tried changing from the Glassfish Administration console as well, both the `default-config` and `server-config`, but no luck.
- WORKAROUND : I can deploy a WAR / Exploded WAR of my Application in glassfish domain folder, and **customize 'domain.xml'** and run the domain in debug mode `./asadmin start-domain --debug domain1`, then I can successfully attach a Remote Debugger. BUT THIS ALLOWS TO ONLY DEBUG MY AGENT CODE and **NOT MY APPLICATION**
- I suppose this is a problem with Intellij IDEA. Does anyone have a fix for this ?

Comment: Check this thread https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-86163#focus=streamItem-27-333017.0-0